# Error logging into Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

This is the strangest thing that just started happening. Whenever I click the signin button in the top right of Visual Studio 2013, it pops up the sign in window but then says "Sorry, we ran into a problem. The online service is not available". I know that's not true because I checked the status on msdn and its fine. I uninstalled and reinstalled and still have the same issue. Anyone ever have this happen?

Comment: I would recommend running a debugging proxy (like Fiddler) that will let you see the request. This will help you verify that the request is making it to their servers correctly.

Comment: How was this solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to wipe my machine and start over. Something just got corrupted somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I passed for the same situation. I set my proxy in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config` and I not logged in VS. After my proxy was free, and didnt not change my proxy that was already set in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config` I changed the proxy and work's, I finally could log in VS.